# The orientation determined by a differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Let me begin with a quote from Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, where my question came from.

> **Proposition 15.5.** *Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold. Any nonvanishing $n$-form $\omega$ on $M$ determines a **unique** orientation  of $M$ for which $\omega$ is positively-oriented at each point. Conversely, if $M$ is given an orientation, then there is a smooth nonvanishing $n$-form on $M$ that is positively-oriented at each point.*

I'm wondering what the uniqueness in the statement is all about. Lee did not stress it in the proof of the proposition. All he did is show that the pointwise orientation on $M$ induced by $\omega$ is actually continuous, making $M$ orientable. However, Lee did pose a remark before the proof that seems to address my question:

> *Remark.* ... It is easy to check that if $\omega$ and $\widetilde{\omega}$ are two positively-oriented smooth $n$-forms on $M$, then $\widetilde{\omega}=f\omega$ for some positive smooth function $f$ on $M$. ...

So the uniqueness is up to a positive function really? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Read 15.5 carefully. What exactly is it that's said to be unique?

Comment: @Arthur Sorry, but I have difficulty coming up with that. If I were to make a guess, I would think the unique orientation on $M$ is none other than the pointwise orientation $p\mapsto\mathcal{O}_{\omega_p}$ related to Proposition 15.3.

Comment: Start with an $n$-dimensional vector space. The space of exterior $n$-forms is $1$-dimensional and therefore the set of nonzero ones has two connected components. Each component is called an orientation of the vector space. A connected manifold is orientable if the bundle of nonzero exterior $n$-forms has two connected components. The choice of one is called an orientation of the manifold. A continuous nowhere zero $n$-form on an $n$-manifold has to lie completely in in one of the connected components. It therefore uniquely determines an orientation.